# Hide table rows for mobile or tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.3 and I want to hide certain columns when in mobile or tablet mode.

Are there specific classes that I can use to hide the columns when in mobile or tablet.

e.g.

```
<td class="mobile-hidden tablet-hidden">blah</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use media queries. Hope you aware of media queries.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .tablet-hidden { display: none; }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about device targeting but you can use the [Utility Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes):

```
.hidden-xs
.hidden-sm
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

There are Bootstrap classes:

- `hidden-xs`
- `hidden-sm`

But, for some reason, there seems to be a glitch where you can only use one of them on some devices.
For exaple, if I have `<td class='hidden-xs hidden-sm'>`, then it only hides for the tablet size, or 'sm'.

Answer (score 0):

Refer link : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

```
.hidden-md-up to hide on medium, large and extra large devices.


.hidden-md-down to hide on medium, small and extra-small devices
```

To display only on medium devices, you can combine the two:

```
hidden-sm-down and hidden-xl-up
```